# Problems running Webots

Tags: webots

When launching Webots instead of a scene in the 3d View window, I sometimes get a black screen. I can not understand the reasons for its occurrence. What could be the cause?

Operating system Windows 8.1, video cards Intell, AMD

Thank you in advance!

I tried to update the driver, but it had no effect. Webots still randomly gives a black screen.

Comment: I think a bug report would be more appropriated than a StackOverflow question: https://github.com/omichel/webots/issues

Answer (score 0):

What is you GPU model? Please make sure that Webots is using the AMD GPU.

If it is not the case make sure to use the latest version of Webots (support for AMD GPU has recently been improved).

In order to understand where does the problem come from, you might use the safe mode of Webots which disables all the advanced OpenGL features (you will then be able to re-enable them one-by-one to check which one is causing problems): https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/starting-webots#safe-mode